# Applying a custom function to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, data-science, apply

I've been struggling for a while at a problem. Actually i want to make a new column in my dataframe which will give 0 for values of 3 columns are below a certain range and give 1 for values exceeding a threshold value. I'm attaching a image of my data head. In my data if value of Ir, Iy and Ib goes above 4 then 1 else 0.
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: add a bit of data (not in image format) and write your desired output.

Comment: welcome to SO! Please read about *How do I ask a good question?* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
import numpy as np

df['new_col'] = np.where(((df['lr'] > 4) & (df['ly'] > 4) & (df['lb'] > 4)), 1, 0)
```

Comment: why not `np.where(df[['lr', 'ly', 'lb']].gt(4).all(axis=1), 1, 0)` ?

Comment: or simply: `df[['lr', 'ly', 'lb']].gt(4).all(axis=1).astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

here an example to do that:
if lr > 0.5 and ly > 0.4 and lb > 0.3

```
import random
import pandas as pd
data = {'lr': [],
        'ly': [],
        'lb': []
       }

for i in range(20):
    r = random.random()
    y = random.random()
    b = random.random()
    data['lr'].append(r)
    data['ly'].append(y)
    data['lb'].append(b)

data

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['new_column'] = 0

filt = (df['lr'] > 0.5) & (df['ly'] > 0.4) & (df['lb'] > 0.3)

df.loc[filt, 'new_column'] = 1
df
```

[image]